# SQL Join three tables keep non-overlapping null values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, presto

I've basically got 2 tables in a DB, plus a dates table that I think I need to join these together for the desired effect.

**Foos**

```
date       | foos
------------------
2016-01-01   2
2016-01-02   3
2016-01-03   4
```

**Bars**

```
date       | bars
------------------
2016-01-02   9
2016-01-03   8
2016-01-04   7
```

**Dates**

```
dates
----------
2016-01-01
2016-01-02
2016-01-03
2016-01-04
...
```

**The desired returned value**

```
date       | bars | foos
-------------------------
2016-01-01   Null   2
2016-01-02   9      3
2016-01-03   8      4
2016-01-04   7      Null
```

What I'm currently doing is selecting my dates table, then left joining foos to dates, then left joining bars to dates.

The problem is that that gives me the following result

```
date       | bars | foos
-------------------------
2016-01-01   Null   2
2016-01-02   9      3
2016-01-03   8      4
2016-01-04   7      Null
2016-01-05   Null   Null
2016-01-06   Null   Null
2016-01-07   Null   Null
...
```

I don't want date returned if bars and foos are both null. I can get it to render in that way, but I'm not sure it's the most efficient way to select, ie:

```
where (bars is not null or foos is not null)
```

Comment: So what is your actual question? Seems to me your last line of code is the solution.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to ask if it's the most efficient way to perform this

Comment: If you try it, does it give a performance problem? Usually it's best to fix performance when it's really an issue, if it's not, you don't have to fix it.

Comment: what you are doing is fine... you can also achieve the same using subqueries... but the performance will always depend on the size of the table and data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following seems to be performant enough for this query.

```
where (bars is not null or foos is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this with `left outer join`

```
select d.dates,b.bars,f.foos from dates d 
left outer join bars b on d.dates = b.date 
left outer join foos f on d.dates = f.date;

+------------+------+------+
| dates      | bars | foos |
+------------+------+------+
| 2016-01-02 |    9 |    3 |
| 2016-01-03 |    8 |    4 |
| 2016-01-04 |    7 | NULL |
| 2016-01-01 | NULL |    2 |
+------------+------+------+
```